# delete node in AST base on condition

Tags: java, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

I am new to use the ANTLR.  I have the ANTLR grammar which creates an AST.  I want to check that if ComparisonExpr contains the FuzzyExpr then I want to delete this ComparisonExpr node and conjunction (“and”, “or”) in front of this ComparisonExpr(if it has) from the AST.  Please suggest me how to do it.  I don’t know that I can do by normal rewrite rule of ANTLR or not?

For example

```
Given the input: where $GPA = #high and age = 25
I want the output like this: where age = 25
(delete the conjunction "and" and ComparisonExpr=>"$GPA = #high") because it has the FuzzyExpr=>"#hight")
```

This is some part of my grammar.

```
grammar Test;
options{
output=AST;
ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

WhereClause      :="where" ExprSingle;
ExprSingle       :OrExpr;
OrExpr           :AndExpr ("or" AndExpr)*;
AndExpr          :ComparisonExpr ("and" ComparisonExpr)*;
ComparisonExpr   :ValueExpr((ValueComp)ValueExpr)?;
ValueExpr        :ValidateExpr
                 |PathExpr 
                 |ExtensionExpr 
                 |FuzzyExpr;
FuzzyExpr        :"#" Literal;
```

Thank you.
Pannipa

Comment: Which version of ANTLR are you using?  It will make a difference for the answer.

Comment: @monty0, the occurrence of `output=AST` in the options suggests the OP is using v3.

Comment: @Bart Kiers, I believe that it could also be ANTLR 2 with those options.

Comment: @monty0, no, in the old v2-times, it was a different syntax: http://www.antlr2.org/doc/options.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this rewrite rules.  Here's a sketch assuming you root your trees with the operator:

```
^(OR e1=expr e2=expr) 
 -> {isFuzzy($e1) && isFuzzy($e2)}? /* empty */
 -> {isFuzzy($e1)}?                 $e2
 -> {isFuzzy($e2)}?                 $e1
 ->                                 ^(OR $e1 $e2)
;
```

You put semantic predicates in front of your tree building statements.  The first predicate to match will choose which tree is written.  If nothing matches the last one will be used.

Comment: Nope, `-> ^()` is illegal. To produce an "empty" AST, simply do `->`, optionally with a comment to make it clear an empty AST is created. Also, you don't want double arrows, `->`, in alternatives. And lastly, `-> ^(X)` equals `-> X`. I took the liberty to edit your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the example is much clearer (and correct) now!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  It is useful for me. I use the ANTLR v.3.

Comment: If this works for you, please accept it as the answer so people will see that your question has been answered.